# How to deploy your python code into an application on Mac?

Tags: python, deployment, tkinter

I've created a python GUI application and the file structure is like this:

```
StockPrediction 
-> StockPrediction
 -> GUI.py
 -> stock.py
->assets
 -> image1.gif
 -> image2.gif
```

Under my GUI.py, the way that the GUI actually runs is through this:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Page()
    root.geometry('850x850')
    root.title("Stock Analyzer")
    root.mainloop()
```

Even as of now, I only know how to run the gui app through PyCharm via the run button. I did the following commands on my terminal but it didn't seem to run:

```
  cd PyCharms 
  cd StockPrediction
  python3 StockPrediction 
  GUI.py
```

This didn't work........

Also, how do I make this code into an application where user can just press a link on my github and then the link will just download the application for the user to just run it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that you will need to use a tool like [py2app](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) to package the program files for Mac.

Comment: I'm using py2app and I did it... but when I went to dist folder and clicked on the app icon, it said GUI error with two buttons console and terminate...........